# Включение условия отбора строк в оконные функции

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица с полями ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_1, ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_2, ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_3, ДАТА, ПОКАЗАТЕЛЬ, ПЛАН_ПОКАЗАТЕЛЯ, KPI_ГРУППЫ_3 и специальное поле ПОСЛЕДНИЙ_ДЕНЬ_МЕСЯЦА, которое принимает значение 1, если значение в поле ДАТА соответствует последнему дню месяца. соответственно мне нужно умножить результат оконной функции по группам уровня 2 на соответствующие значения KPI_группы_2, при соблюдении условия, что ПОСЛЕДНИЙ_ДЕНЬ_МЕСЯЦА = 1. Проблема в добавлении вот этого KPI, своего для каждого группы уровня 2 на конец месяца. Пока что код запроса без KPI выглядит так:

```
SELECT
    ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_1,
    ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_2,
    ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_3, 
    SUM(ПОКАЗАТЕЛЬ) OVER(PARTITION BY ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_3) /
    SUM(ПЛАН_ПОКАЗАТЕЛЯ) OVER(PARTITION BY ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_3) * {Место для сомножителя - КPI по ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_3 при условии ПОСЛЕДНИЙ_ДЕНЬ_МЕСЯЦА = 1} KPI_ГРУПП_3
FROM ТАБЛИЦА
WHERE ДАТА BETWEEN X AND Y AND... AND... AND...
```

Как дополнить код в фигурных скобках, чтобы получилось законченное умножение? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case подойдёт?

```
select deptno, 
   sum(sal) over (partition by deptno ) * 
   case when mod(rownum,2)=0 then 2 else 1 end  AS aaa 
 from emp;
```

или

```
select  
   sum(ПЛАН_ПОКАЗАТЕЛЯ) over (partition by ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_3) * 
   case when ПОСЛЕДНИЙ_ДЕНЬ_МЕСЯЦА = 1 
        then Место для сомножителя - КPI по ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_3 
        else 1 
   end AS KPI_ГРУПП_3 
 from ТАБЛИЦА;
```